# How to compile resources folder with Maven command

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm using mvn compile to compile my Maven webapp. This project has a resources folder instead of the java folder created for a .jar project. My problem is that mvn finds no sources, and I haven't find a way in the maven docs to proceed this way. Is there a way, either by mvn command options or by pom.xml modification to make mav aware of the resources folder and compile it?

I know changing the name from resources to java makes the deal, but that's a spureous way to proceed.

Comment: Can you show us the layout of your project and may be you can post your pom file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include additional source directories in your project you can use the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html)

So for example the following configuration will add the `src/main/resources` folder of your project as a source folder.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${basedir}/src/main/resource</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but I'm surprised that I've to specify the autogenerated resources folder as an additional folder to compile sources. Do I compile anything when I execute a "mvn compile" on a webapp project? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your .classpath file. That should have what folders including src and test are added. You can then add additional resources. I would normally use the IDE to look at the build path and add/exclude resources.

Comment: Where is it located? Neither in my maven installation folder nor in the repo. Can I create a .classpath file?